# Can we Custom timestamp in elasticserch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have logstash and elasticsearch running and indexing and it used created date as timestampe. I have a message  in the log which is in format

`t  message         2018-01-21 23:55:00.266  INFO`

I am not able to use the timestamp in the message for indexing. Is there any way we can achieve this?
My current logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/elk/*/*/*.log"
    type => "log"
    #start_position => "beginning"
    max_open_files => 80000
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
  }
}
```

And an example log line:

```
2018-02-06 10:36:21.607 DEBUG [finer,3c5f365003b590ce,025357cdf9dbf3ac,true] 7 --- [nio-9095-exec-3] c.t.finexp.services.impl.MongoService : MongoService find one the collection: external_loanofficer with map input{"nmlsId":"87207"}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to move the timestamp to a separate field in the record. I would use logstash grok filter for this.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

After that you can specify in Kibana which field you want to use as timestamp, or you can try and override the generated timestamp with the grok filter.
First I would use a grok filter then on the result a date filter:

```
filter{
  grok{
    match=>{"message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:DateTime} %{WORD:level} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
  }
  date{
    match=>["t","UNIX_MS"]
    target=>"timestamp"
  }
}
```

The date filter was not tested, you can check the grok filter on this site:

> http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

The 'level' is not required in the grok pattern, feel free to remove it.

Comment: I added like this

`filter {
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    }
  }`

and restarted logstash but nothing changed.

Comment: please give me a full log line and your current logstash config, with that I can tell more

Comment: **`input {
  file {
    path => "/elk/*/*/*.log"
    type => "log"
#    start_position => "beginning"
    max_open_files => 80000
  }

}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
  }
}`**

and full log message is 

**`2018-02-06 10:36:21.607 DEBUG [finer,3c5f365003b590ce,025357cdf9dbf3ac,true] 7 --- [nio-9095-exec-3] c.t.finexp.services.impl.MongoService    : MongoService find one the collection: external_loanofficer with map input{"nmlsId":"87207"}`**

Comment: I tried with the below config, This creates a new field but is not updating the timestamp.

`filter{
grok {
match => ["message", "(?<Original_Time>%{YEAR}.%{MONTHNUM}.%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
}
date {
match => [ "Original_Time", "yyyy/mmm/dd:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
target => "timestamp"
remove_field => ["OrginalLogTime"]
  }
}`

Comment: Sry, by 'using' I thought you meant 'accessing' not 'replacing'. You could try targeting @timestamp in the date plugin, but I'm not sure it would work. Worth a try.